# Question related to probability density function

Tags: probability-distributions, solution-verification

A continuous random variable X has the probability density function

$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 px+q & 1 \leq x \leq 4 \\
 0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

If $P(X<2)=\dfrac{1}{9}$ , find the values of $p$ and $q$. $\left[ans: p= \dfrac{1}{9},\ q=\dfrac{1}{18}  \right] $

---

This is my attempt,

\begin{aligned}
P(X < 2) &= \dfrac{1}{9}\\
P(X \leq 2) &= \dfrac{1}{9} \\
\int_1^2 (px+q) \,dx &= \dfrac{1}{9} \\
\left[\dfrac{px^2}{2}+qx \right]_1^2 &= \dfrac{1}{9} \\
2p+2q- \left( \dfrac{p}{2}+q\right) &= \dfrac{1}{9} \\
\dfrac{3}{2} +q &= \dfrac{1}{9} \qquad(1) \\
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \,dx &= 1 \\
\int_{1}^{4} (px+q) \,dx &= 1 \\
\left[\dfrac{px^2}{2}+qx \right]_1^4 &= 1 \\
8p+4q- \left( \dfrac{p}{2}+q\right) &= 1 \\
\dfrac{15}{2} +3q &= 1  \qquad(2)  \\ 
\end{aligned}

By solving both $(1)$ and $(2)$, I get $p=\dfrac{2}{9} \text{ and } q=- \dfrac{2}{9}$

Can someone check my work? Thanks.

Comment: I find the same answers as you. So I think you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:please check (1) and (2)

$$\frac{3p}{2}+q=\frac{1}{9}(1)$$

$$\frac{15p}{2}+3q=1(2)$$

$$p=\frac{2}{9} , q= \frac {-2}{9}$$

same answer